# Two different datasources for SearchDisplayController and TableView

Tags: ios, iphone, uitableview

how can i have different datasource for SearchDisplayController and TableView on the same View?
Like Facebook app, i need the search bar to search and display data from a datasource, while the TableView shows data from another array.
How can i achieve that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Setup two instance variables within your view controller. One to hold the data for your searchdisplay controller and one to hold your tableview data. In the corresponding delegate method, use the correct instance variable.

Comment: It's soooooo easy now, 'cos you got friends you can trust....
Thank you friend :)